# Div margin: auto vs align: center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have 2 divs below each other. I want them both to be centered horizontally. The thing is that I have to use `align: center` for the `#wrapper` and `margin: auto` for the other. Otherwise only 1 of them is centered. If I use `align-center` for both, only the #wrapper is centered, if I use `margin: auto` for both, only the second one is centered.

Why I have to use 2 different properties to align them in the center?:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2" id="col1"> col1 </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2 " id="col2"> col2 </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2" id="col3"> col3 </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="below">
Centered div below the #wrapper div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
#col1{
    background-color: lime;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#col2{ 
    background-color:  aqua;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#col3{
    background-color:  lightpink;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper{
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 10%;
    width: 50%;
    align: center;
}

#below{
    border: solid 2px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 80%;   
    clear: both;  
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you make a codepen or jsfiddle of this? `text-align` and `margin: auto` have different use cases which you may be confused of, or having to hack into your layout to get bootstrap to work. btw... take a look at Zurb's Foundation. Bootstrap is not a good framework for anything more than a demo. Even then... use Foundation if you need a framework.

Answer (score 3):

`align` isn't a valid CSS property - it is an attribute available on the `<table>` element, but one that is discouraged from use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Attributes

Using `align` in your CSS should have no effect.

---

`margin: 0 auto;` affects the container directly, and when the container is block-level (`display: block`).

`text-align: center` affects text, inline, and inline-block level *children* of a container - not the container itself.

---

It's important to distinguish between the two:

centering a block-level element: use `margin: 0 auto;`

centering text, inline, or inline-block level children: use `text-align: center;`

---

In light of that, check that `#wrapper` is block-level i.e. `display: block`. If it isn't, or it has a parent that inhibits its width, then it won't center with margin, unless you go into the `display: flex` world, which you shouldn't really explore until you grasp the fundamentals of block and inline-block level elements.

I've written an article explaining how to leverage the basic display properties, supplemented with interactive Codepen demos: http://fixate.it/blog/css-display-properties/

Comment: I am not using `text-align`, I am using `align`

Comment: edited - `align` isn't a valid property. `align-self`, and `align-items` are the closest you're going to get to `align`, but only in the context of `display: [inline-]flex`

Comment: Great explanation. Been developing for years and `text-align: center;` affecting children only evaded me until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***Div margin: auto vs align: center***

**`margin: 0 auto` When can you use it?**
When will you need to set center align any `div` or any block like main parent `container` in this case you have to use `margin: 0 auto` with `display: table` it be will set your section center of parent section.

**`text-align: center` When can you use it?**
When will you need to set center align any `Text Paragraph` or `Image` in this case you have to use `text-align: center` it will be set your text-paragraph or image center of