# How to center text in a row using Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The problem is that `<p>` and `<h1>` are appearing on same line and no matter what I do they can't be centered.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="appSummary">
    <h1>Why This App Is Awesome</h1>
    <p class="lead">Summary, once again, of your app's awesomeness</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#appSummary{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Also you can try add: class="text-center"

Comment: @dpretrini i also told h1 and p are on same line. and i tried that already

Comment: youve also missed off a div which defines the columns, that might cause unnecessary errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap 4 which uses the flex model, change your CSS rule to:

```
#appSummary{
    justify-content:center;
}
```

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/zcn84QPlzO)**

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? I love it when someone downvotes a proper solution a) without explaining themselves and b) when they're clearly wrong

Comment: I dont know who downvoted. Well thanks it is working. Can you explain me a bit of flex model. I think it is the every problem that most of the thing i follow from internet is not working. and also h1 and p are not on same line

Comment: @j08691 whoever downvoted isnt wrong, as i stated in my comment on the question, missing out the div with a column definition will cause unnecessary errors

Comment: @SamratLuitel Sure, the flex model is a newer way to position elements. There's too much info on it to go over in a comment, but I recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes to learn more.

Comment: May I also ask the reason why h1 and p tag are not appearing on separate line

Comment: @SamratLuitel try adding a div with a column definition. without it, the width wont behave correctly

Comment: @mast3rd3mon ok sure but why does h1 and p appear on same line

Comment: @SamratLuitel i already commented why: `@j08691 whoever downvoted isnt wrong, as i stated in my comment on the question, missing out the div with a column definition will cause unnecessary errors`

Comment: @SamratLuitel They're on the same line because of your layout. The row is set to display:flex and because of the flexbox model, all children are by default now flex items. I highly recommend reading up on the model so you best understand how it works.

Comment: @j08691 Thank you I am new to this flex model

Answer (score 15):

The best way to do this is to wrap the text in a column that has the class **`text-center`**.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="appSummary">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h1>Why This App Is Awesome</h1>
      <p class="lead">Summary, once again, of your app's awesomeness</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

An other way to do this is to use the class `justify-content-center` on the row, but without the column things **may break**.

Answer (score 3):

Use d-flex flex-column : more [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="appSummary">
            <h1>Why This App Is Awesome</h1>
            <p class="lead">Summary, once again, of your app's awesomeness</p>

        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Found the following on your link and worked perfectly for me: `<div class="row justify-content-center">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin: auto` for centering item, rather than `text-align: center`
why?

> `margin: 0 auto;` affects the container directly, and when the container
>   is block-level (display: block).
>
> `text-align: center;` center affects text, inline, and inline-block level
>   children of a container - not the container itself.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337977/div-margin-auto-vs-align-center)

i created example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaytjmya/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <h1 class="text-center">
      Services
```

The class, text-center inside h1 tag will automatically center the text written inside the h1 tag in bootstrap 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 text-center">
<h3>Its this easy</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Text-center is the easy way to center text in bootstrap when you use a "col" div, the text will then automatically be in the center. You can also make this responsive to different screen widths, eg "text-md-center" makes anything above and including 768px centered text.